# Adding images, classes and coordinates of bounding boxes into a csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, machine-learning, computer-vision, bounding-box

I have an output folder where I have multiple images produced by my inference file. Each image has multiple bounding boxes with class labels (2 categories) and confidence score.

In my Inference.py file I return the bounding boxes like this:

```
image, bboxes, det_classes, ret = detector.run(image_name)
```

When I print the bboxes, it gives me the bounding box arrays for all the images:

[boundingbox arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSycO.png)

Then for the purpose of saving these coordinates to a csv file I did this:

```
pd.DataFrame(bboxes).to_csv("path/to/file.csv")
```

But it adds only bounding boxes for the first image as shown:

[CSV file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5ftU.png)

I want to add the 1st image bounding box coordinates plus the image id/dir and the class label in the first row and so on. In other words, if an image New1.png has 3 bounding boxes then all those 3 bounding boxes should have New1.png as there image id/dir and class label according to the detected class, and then the coordinates as shown:

[CSV file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFcJ9.png)

I am a beginner to this field so if I have missed explaining something above kindly ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

paths = np.array([
    'New1.png', 'New2.png', 'New3.png', 'New4.png'
])

category = np.array([
    'car', 'bike', 'car', 'bike'
])

coordinates = np.array([
    [23,24,25,26,27],
    [15,18,10,91,22],
    [56,41,79,32,82],
    [19,33,50,94,20],
])

# Create DataFrame from above arrays
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ImageId':paths,
    'Detected Category':category,
    'coordinate 1': [x[0] for x in coordinates],
    'coordinate 2': [x[1] for x in coordinates],
    'coordinate 3': [x[2] for x in coordinates],
    'coordinate 4': [x[3] for x in coordinates],
    'coordinate 5': [x[4] for x in coordinates],
})
# Save DataFrame
df.to_csv('dataframe.csv', index=False)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Actually, is it possible that the python script **automatically** writes the ImageId (which is available in the form of paths e.g "some/path/to/image1.png") and suppose if image1.png has 5 bounding boxes then the image1.png should be written down 5 times with each row specific to its bounding box coordinates and class labels?

Comment: @ElectAI That would be another question.

Comment: actually I wanted this but I guess could not express in the above question. Should I create another question?

Comment: Dear Mushfirat my upvote has been recorded. I wanted to ask that can you kindly make a post explaining all this in a new question? otherwise I will create a new question no worries. Thanks